# Calling multiple EJB methods in JSF managed bean, do each run in same or separate transaction?

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, transactions, ejb, managed-bean

I have the following managed bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class View {
  @EJB
  private Bar bar

  public void foo() {
     bar.do();
     bar.do();
     bar.do();
  }
}
```

Will this lead to 3 single transactions (one for each `bar.do()` call) or will this lead to 1 transaction (`foo()`) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have 3 separate transactions, since EJB container starts the transaction on the beginning of the bean method and ends it when the method is finished (this is done automatically for [Container Managed Transactions](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncij.html), with [Bean Managed Transactions](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnciy.html) you do this manually).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use just 1 transaction and more then one EJB method call, then 1., use the session facade design pattern. Create a facae bean with CMT (Container Managed Transaction) to call the other beans within its own transaction.
2., Use BMT (Bean Managed Transaction)